# VLOOKUP Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, vlookup

```
VLOOKUP( $ObjectType.I__c.Fields.ISO_Code__c,  
$ObjectType.I__c.Fields.Name,   Case__r.Account.BillingCountry) + '-' + IF(OR(TEXT(Case__r.Account.Type) = 'Cargo Agent',TEXT(Case__r.Account.Type) = 'C Associate') ,'C','P') + '-' +  LEFT(Case__r.Account.ICode__c,7)
```

This allows me to upload something like this format `JO-P-NA44694-2.pdf` but the user can also upload something like `[[JO-P-NA44694-2]].pdf` or `--JO-P-NA44694-2-][.pdf`. How can I stop that, and make the user only able to upload something like this `JO-P-NA44694-2.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Regex something like this `REGEX(Name, "[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}")`